# How can I remove server header in nginx docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I install nginx:1.15.6 container by docker-compose file and I want to remove Server header from all nginx responses, by the search I found bellow way 
set "more_set_headers 'Server: custom';" in nginx configuration but there is an error to respond . How can I remove server header in nginx docker? I think I should install "headers-more-nginx-module-0.33" module but I dont know how can i install it :(

error :

```
[emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "more_set_headers" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:22
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: nginx
    container_name: r_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/ssl
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build: phpfpm
    container_name: r_php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./phpfpm/raya.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/custom.ini
      - ./code:/code
```

default.conf :

```
server_tokens off;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols     TLSv1.1  TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private.key;

    index index.php index.html;
    #server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    error_page 404 403 402 401 422 = /errors/error.php;
    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 = /errors/error.php;

#   bellow line get error :
#   more_set_headers "Server: custom";

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }


    location ~ /assets/ {
    }

    location / {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `Dockerfile` of your nginx and the nginx configuration as well ?

Comment: docker file is just for test, there is just one line : FROM nginx:1.15.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`more_set_headers` is a part of the [headers_more](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/) module, so it needs an additional nginx package to work properly. `nginx-extras` could be installed while building docker image for nginx container:

```
FROM nginx:1.15.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx-extras
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks it works but I need to install module manually , can you help me to install module from package ? "headers-more-nginx-module-0.33.tar.gz"

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can use [ADD instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) in the `Dockerfile` to automatically unpack your local archive as a directory into container and then follow [instructions](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation) of module installation (using `RUN` instruction).

Comment: nginx alpine doesn't have apt-get,  I am trying to use apk, but not able to install nginx-extras. Please help..

Comment: @amesh I believe the module in alpine is called [`nginx-mod-http-headers-more`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/nginx-mod-http-headers-more)

I know it's been a while, but we just stumbled with the same issue in our team, hope it still helps :)

Comment: Hey devs, could you share your dockerfile that let you install this ?
Iw as getting an error running the apt-get command in the dockerfie :)

Comment: it completely blows my mind the fact that removing a useless header which is a security flaw requires installing additional modules

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that worked for me. I took out the version numbers and stripped down the config with only what is really needed.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server_tokens off; # hides version on 404 or 500 pages
more_clear_headers 'Server'; # removes Server header from response headers

server {
    ...
}
```